# ReactJS (create-react-app) and Django backend - best way to handle auth?

Tags: django, reactjs

What's the best method to handle auth with reactjs and a django backend? Any libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if [Django-Rest-Framework authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) suits you. They have a view ways to do it e.g. token and session authentication.